# Comparing date strings with jsonpath expression

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I'm trying to run the following query, which unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation looks as like it should be possible.

```
SELECT id, profile
FROM end_user
WHERE profile @? '$.first_segment_exited_at ? (@.datetime() < "2023-05-25".datetime())'::jsonpath;
```

This is [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) which leads me to think I should be able to achieve this:

> string . datetime() → datetime_type (see note)
>
> Date/time value converted from a string
>
> jsonb_path_query('["2015-8-1", "2015-08-12"]', '$[*] ? (@.datetime() <
> "2015-08-2".datetime())') → "2015-8-1"

Example profile data, note the dates are valid ISO format;

```
{
  "first_segment_exited_at": "2023-05-22T03:09:37.825Z",
}
```

The following query returns results, but I'm keen on switching to jsonpath syntax in order to utilize an index

```
select id, profile
from end_user
where '2023-05-25'::timestamptz > (profile->>'first_segment_exited_at')::timestamptz
```

I'm running Postgres v14.

Comment: I'd simplify that to `profile @? '$.first_segment_exited_at.datetime() < "2023-05-25".datetime()'`

Comment: That does indeed seem to give me some results @Bergi!

Comment: Actually too many results  looks like it isn't applying the condition at all, I'm getting all rows back 

Comment: Oh wait that should have used `@@` not `@?`. But still, [both approaches seem to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/-F-sFI5g), can you make a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: Seems the problem was it being unable to parse a JSON stringifyied date in a JSON field 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illegal JSON datetime format in the table column. This works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE end_user (id int, profile jsonb);
INSERT INTO end_user VALUES
  (1, '{"first_segment_exited_at": "2023-05-22T03:09:37.825Z"}')
, (2, '{"first_segment_exited_at": "2023-05-22T03:09:37Z"}')  -- no fractional sec
, (3, '{"first_segment_exited_at": "2023-05-22T03:09:37"}')   -- no trailing "Z", either
;

SELECT *
FROM   end_user
WHERE  profile @? '$.first_segment_exited_at ? (@.datetime() < "2023-05-25".datetime())';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PzW0WOvV)

Row 3 is the only one with legal format.
(The filter expression needs to be valid, too.)

You didn't get an error message because, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

> The `jsonpath` operators `@?` and `@@` suppress the following errors:
> missing object field or array element, unexpected JSON item type,
> datetime and numeric errors. [...] This behavior might be helpful when
> searching JSON document collections of varying structure.

To debug input strings, test with a function that doesn't suppress the error. Like [`jsonb_path_query_first()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first('{"d": "2023-05-22T03:09:37.1"}', '$.d.datetime()')
```

```
ERROR:  datetime format is not recognized: "2023-05-22T03:09:37.1"
HINT:  Use a datetime template argument to specify the input data format.
```

But  this one flies:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first('{"d": "2023-05-22T03:09:37"}', '$.d.datetime()')
```

Also, you can supply a template pattern to the `.datetime()` method like [Laurenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) demonstrates in his added answer. (More obstacles ahead ...)

Comment: Very confusing given ::timestamptz converts that format correctly and that format is the result of the following JS code 

`JSON.stringify(new Date())` => `'"2023-05-24T04:56:11.007Z"'`

`select '2023-05-22T03:47:35.953Z'::timestamptz` => `2023-05-22 15:47:35.953 +1200`

Comment: @Tim: I agree it's confusing. Even worse since the operator suppresses the error message. I added some debug help above. (I vaguely remember a discussion why the trailing "Z" in timestamp strings was not recognized by default, but can't find it now.)

Comment: And the behaviour seems to contradict the documentation, which says "*The `datetime()` method sequentially tries to match its input string to the ISO formats for `date`, `timetz`, `time`, `timestamptz`, and `timestamp`. It stops on the first matching format and emits the corresponding data type.*"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your date is not in a format that `datetime()` recognizes, and you have to specify a template string with `datetime()`. Use the following `jsonpath`:

```
'$.first_segment_exited_at ? (@.datetime("YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS.MS\"Z\"") < "2023-05-25".datetime())'::jsonpath
```

I had to use the (I believe undocumented) PostgreSQL extension of double quoted literal format strings to match the `T` and `Z` in the string.

Comment: Thanks but that date is literally the result of stringifying a date in JS i.e. `JSON.stringify(new Date())`

Comment: I looked and found the statement that datetime formats in JSON are not standardized. While the format is certainly justifyable, the fact remains that PostgreSQL doesn't understand it by default. You might want to complain to PostgreSQL or write a patch that improves that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The documentation says "*The `datetime()` method sequentially tries to match its input string to the ISO formats for `date`, `timetz`, `time`, `timestamptz`, and `timestamp`. It stops on the first matching format and emits the corresponding data type.*"

Comment: @Bergi Right. However, as far as I know, there isn't "the ISO format". There are many possible formats allowed by ISO 8601, and this one happens not to be accepted by PostgreSQL's JSONPATH implementation.